# Wrong address results from Geocoder object

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I have an Android app that shows the user's current location based on the device's coordinates (lat/lon) - to get the current address I use the Geocoder object like below:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)
```

After getting complains from some users that the address reported is not accurate I have investigated a few cases and found out that the problem is happening with the Geocoder object - in these cases, the address reported is a few blocks away. If I use the same coordinates with the Google Geocode API the address is correctly reported. Note that the Geocoder object results are not always inaccurate.

Is there a way to make the Geocoder always return accurate results?

Comment: Typically web service calls provide more precise results. If you can implement web service calls from your app it might solve the issue.

Comment: You are correct; using the geocoder API provides correct results. The problem is that recently Google has started charging for the API calls and that would yield extremely large charges for me, that is why I have decided to use the Geocoder.

Comment: Geocoder class uses a different search stack internally and this leads to different results comparing to the web service. Hopefully one day Google will unify the internal infrastructure and native geocoder will work exactly the same as a web service. Currently it doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks. That explains the strange behavior.